# Recurring Payments in PayPal

Tags: paypal, payment, recurring-billing

I am trying to use the Recurring payment API offered by PayPal.
I have a scenario which I am not able to address directly. It goes like this.

We have a website where we sell some services. Now the services are charged per user license. A user can buy/cancel user license in between. We want to offer the customer a recurring billing option. We have to notice here that the amount may vary each billing cycle based on the number of user licenses the customer uses during that cycle.

Is there any way I can achieve this using PayPal recurring Payment API's.

Answer (score 7):

I realize this is a very old post, but it still shows up for Google searches, so I thought I'd add:

Paypal does allow you to do this now, using their new [adaptive payments api](https://www.x.com/community/ppx/adaptive_payments).

Authorize.net also has a service that might work called [Customer Information Manager](http://developer.authorize.net/api/cim/).

Comment: Hi Peter, thanks for taking time to answer this. Adaptive payments is really a good addition. Though it does not handle the scenario I needed to solve, it is really a much needed feature.                             * I don't work on this any longer.

Comment: @Peter: Hi Peter, Although I know this is quite old post, I´m facing same scenario, so am interested in this solution. I have read Paypal doc, and I see they say you can set variable amount subscriptions with adaptative payments api, but I can´t find out how to do it. Could you please provide some more details on sequence of the operations to use?

Answer (score 4):

The recurring payment option is a fixed amount that the customer pre-agrees to pay each month (or period).  To do what you're trying to do, a customer would have to pre-agree to pay whatever amount you decide to charge at a later time.  This means pre-authorizing an unknown payment amount, which will not be allowed by any payment service.

Your only options are:

1. Bill the variable amount each month (i.e. no subscription).
2. Set up a subscription where the monthly amount is the maximum that could potentially be billed, and then refund the difference each month.

Good luck with #2 - I would never agree to such a thing as a customer, personally.

Comment: Option 1 indeed seems the only acceptable way to do that, IMO.

Comment: I missed the reasoning you provided of "pre-authorizing an unknown payment". Now it makes perfect sense to my on why things are the way they are.
Since in this scenario change of amount is not so frequent, I would go for deleting the existing profile and creating a new one.

Answer (score 1):

What you're looking for is covered in the UK by the Direct Debit system, however given the potential for abuse it's very tightly controlled and there are a lot of restrictions and regulations governing it.

I'd strongly suggest you just set up a monthly invoicing system that just bills the client each month.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know its meaning full or not as it is a very old post.

Instead of creating recurring profile on PayPal Server, You can store the customer's credit card on the PayPal using REST API: https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/#vault then every month you can fetch it and charge it like recurring Payment Or When client is no longer with the services then just remove its card from PayPal.

I suppose Authorize.net SIM method also does the same.

Hope this make sense.