# API of Direct Debit of Paypal

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0, paypal, paypal-sandbox

I need API of Direct Debit PayPal. How can I get that. I search it on Google and other search engine, even I post that question on PayPal community also, but I hadn't got any answer from them. So much confused about that matter. I got a related answer in this forum but that was not helpful. So anyone can help me. Feeling mad now

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/277750/recurring-payments-in-paypal? is that what you looking for?

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I have visit your url but unfortunately the links that are given in that post is not working any more. Can you provide me some link on recurring payments of PayPal

Comment: There are few PHP classes if you google around. Try this http://drewjoh.com/wiki/code/classes/phppaypal .. i used that classes for my previous project ;)

Answer (score 0):

PayPal doesn't have any API calls for "Direct Debit" but there is Direct Payment. It's an API call where you pass item and billing information (credit card number, billing address, and things like that) to PayPal for processing. Your buyers aren't redirect to PayPal at all.

The Merchant SDK found here has a working example of Direct Payment, Express Checkout, and Recurring Payments if you wanted to try it out - http://paypal.github.io/

And some documentation on Direct Payment: 
https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/paypal-payments-pro/integration-guide/WPDirectPayment/

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But I got my answer. Direct debit is a payment term used in BACS in UK. So I wanted to know, is there any this type of transaction in PayPal? And I had got the answer after a long r&d